# Unable to Add/ Edit Post in WordPress

Tags: posts

I have read all the posts related to the problem but the problem isn't solving. You can click on the link below.

https://ibb.co/R4ZyjXL

The content area has shrunk and SEO Yoast fields can't be seen. I have done already;

1. Disable all plugins and reactivate them one by one
2. Check the website in the health checker plugin
3. Already check the Add post by activating default theme but the problem persists.
4. Rename/ delete the.htaccess, update the permalink
5. Already checked by instaling disable gutenberg plugin
6. All plugins/ WordPress are up to date.

Any help will be appreciated. Also, if I delete the classic editor plugin, the page goes blank.

Regards

Comment: Did you check if CSS is used in Additional CSS section available in Appearances - Customizations to override some text field? You said you have disabled all plugins? Including security plugin?

Comment: Have you tried opening your browser console to see if there are any JS errors? Have you been using Classic Editor all along or have you done anything in the Block Editor?